# Solve the Diophantine equation $2xy + 3y^{2} = 24$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

> Solve the equation $$2xy + 3y^{2} = 24, \qquad x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$$

---

I tried by stating that $x$ and $y$ cannot both be odd and that y cannot be odd. So either $x$ and $y$ are both even or $x$ is even and $y$ is odd. Then I was trying take the residues modulo $3$ and modulo $8$ but could not arrive at a conclusion. Please help me solve this further.

Comment: To help you solve this "further", you ought to mention the actual outcome of your attempts to take residues modulo $3$ and $8$, whether or not those attempts led to a complete resolution of the problem.

Comment: You could try to solve a quadratic $3y^2 + 2xy  - 24=0$, you would have a discriminant that depends on the value of $x$. So with trial and error, you could find the values of x that make the discriminant a square.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have rightly pointed out, y can never be even.

Now note that the equation can be written as $y∗(2x+3y)=24$. Thus $y$ must be an integer factor of $24$.

You will thus get the following results : -
$y=2,4,6,8,12$.

So this will give you $(x,y)=\{(3,2), (-3, -2),(−3,4),(3,-4),(−7,6),(7,-6),(−17,12),(17,-12)\}$

Only 8 does not give any solution.
So here is the solution you asked for.

Comment: The answer is correct. But what you have done is basically copying. You have just copied the previous answer and it's comments and pasted it here. If you had to say something, then you could always say it in the comments there.

Answer (score 3):

Equation can be written as $y*(2x+3y)=24$. Thus $y$ must be an integer factor of $24$. This should get you to a manageable range of possibilities.

Comment: Basically I am getting $y = 2, 4, 6, 8, 12$. So this is giving me $(x,y) = \{(3,2), (-3,4), (-7,6), (-17,12)\}$ Only $8$ does not give any solution. So I just want to ask if I am correct in this statement.

Comment: You might want to note that if $(x,y)$ is a solution, so is $(-x,-y)$. (Note: "$y$ must be an integer factor of $24$"--so negative values of $y$ are possible.)